# Helm Charts for Jenkins-X?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, jenkins-x

I have been searching for ages for a community driven helm chart for Jenkins-X. I can find them for regular jenkins, but I need to setup Jenkins-x, and I just can't seem to find any information,

Answer (score 3):

we recommend you don't try and install jenkins x via a chart - but via the CLI install tool we've built using [jx create cluster](https://jenkins-x.io/getting-started/create-cluster/) if you don't have a kubernetes cluster or [jx install](https://jenkins-x.io/getting-started/install-on-cluster/) if you do.

Jenkins X requires lots of things to be setup (git repos, git/docker registry/jenkins tokens, ingress, TLS, DNS et al) - doing it by hand via a helm chart is gonna be very hard

Comment: I looked at the jx create cluster link... but it seems to cover everything except when you have kubernetes in an aws environment. I can't seem to find anything that will help me get this running in a cluster on aws.

Comment: if you have a kubernetes cluster use `jx install`: https://jenkins-x.io/getting-started/install-on-cluster/

Answer (score 1):

Quick googling gave me https://github.com/jenkins-x/jenkins-x-platform/tree/master/jenkins-x-platform. Have you tried that?

Comment: Thanks, I missed that on their repo list at the org level - could only see code for the actual applications!

Comment: This actually wasn't helpful in the end - it's for a whole load of other stuff we don't need, and it doesn't really work.